# FlutterFire authentication using role authentication

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to sign in based on the role of the user from firebase. But mostly, the tutorials i saw are using older firebase version, therefore I'm using firebase documentation and my logic.

here is my function for auth role sign in

```
Future<User?> signIn(String email, String password) async {
    try {
      UserCredential userCredential = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email, password: password);
      User? user = userCredential.user;
      await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('users')
          .doc(user!.uid)
          .get()
          .then((DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
            var docData = documentSnapshot.data();
            var role = docData['role'];

        if (documentSnapshot.data()['roles'] == 'dosen') {
          return 'ok';
        } else {
          return 'err';
        }
      });
      return user;
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      if (e.code == 'user-not-found') {
        print('No user found for that email.');
      } else if (e.code == 'wrong-password') {
        print('Wrong password provided for that user.');
      }
    }
  }
```

but mostly having problem with this section
the error is like this
"The method '[]' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'.  Try making the call conditional (using '?.') or adding a null check to the target ('!')."

```
await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('users')
          .doc(user!.uid)
          .get()
          .then((DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
            var docData = documentSnapshot.data();
            var role = docData['role'];

        if (documentSnapshot.data()['roles'] == 'dosen') {
          return 'ok';
        } else {
          return 'err';
        }
      });
```

Thank you.

---------------EDIT---------------

i've solved it using this

```
Map<String, dynamic> data =
            documentSnapshot.data()! as Map<String, dynamic>;
```

so then i can pass the data using string, in which i call it like this

```
role = data['role'].toString();
```

thank you for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

REPLACE THIS:

```
if (documentSnapshot.data()['roles'] == 'dosen')
```

WITH:

```
if (documentSnapshot.data()!['roles'] == 'dosen')
```

Comment: it says "The method 'get' isn't defined for the type 'Object'.  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'get'."

Comment: try now I have eddited

Comment: thank you anas nadeem for the solution, i tried using your code, but it still doesn't work.. maybe i didn't use some of the required widgets. but, i tried reading throught the docs and use my logic and i did it! hooray